# jQuery autocomplete does not stop loading data when removing characters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery's autocomplete with remote datasource in MVC3. I have an action in the controller like this:

```
public ActionResult AutoCompleteSource(string term)
{
    var result = // load some values filtered by term
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In cshtml I use autocomplete like this:

```
var dataSource = '@Url.Action("AutoCompleteSource", "someControllerName");
$("#inputId").autocomplete(
    {
        minLength: 2,
        source: dataSource
    });
```

This works so the dataSource is always reloaded when the user changes something in the input textbox.

When typing 2 characters it loads something. During the reloading the user types a 3rd character, so it stops reloading the action with only two characters and restarts reloading with the three characters.

The problem is the following: When the user types in two characters it loads something. During loading the user removes one character, so now it should actually STOP reloading the dataSource, because with only one character, autocomplete should stop working. But it doesn't, it continues loading with the two character term and also displays the result, even though the user has deleted one character, so actually it should display nothing.

Did you encounter this behaviour too, and what can I do about it?